# Can I arrange the files in a folder by the method "Group According to type" in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

In Windows, you have an option to **group the files according to type** in which for example all .txt files are displayed under text files and .exe files under exe or .obj under obj.

I mean all the files of the same extension / type are displayed under the respective groups.

So can I do this in Nautilus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select `View -> List`, and then click on `Type` column.

[image]

Comment: Is it not possible in the ICON view instead of LIST view?

Comment: Note, Ubuntu (Linux in general) does not use .xxx file extensions used by Windows to determine file type. One could rename a text file as something.png and Ubuntu would still classify it is a text file.

Comment: yeah...thats true...but the group view really is a very usefull view to find files fast!

Comment: @Nirmik I believe that if you first select `View->List`, then click on `Type` to group the files according to its extension and then click back to `View->Icon`, the order will be kept so you will have an Icon view group by extensions.

Comment: actually in Icon view also the option for arranging according to type is there(right click->arrange by) but that does not GROUP them! they still stay continous in view.